# Solving $ T' = 0 $ for distributions in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Denoting $ T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n) $ as distributions with $ T_f(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\varphi\ dx $, I wish to prove the distribution solution of the equation $ T' = 0 $ (distribution derivative) is $ T = T_c $ where $c$ is constant.
 I have a proof for $\mathbb{R}$, where for all $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ we can have $ \varphi = \psi + \varphi_0 T_1(\varphi) $ where $$ \psi = \varphi - \varphi_0 T_1(\varphi) $$ choosing $ \varphi_0 \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}) $ such that $ T_1(\varphi_0) = \int_\mathbb{R} \varphi_0 dx =1 $. Hence we have $ T_1(\psi)= \int_\mathbb{R}\psi dx = 0 $, so for $ \tau(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \psi(t)dt $ we have $ \psi = \tau'$. Hence if $ T' = 0 $ then
$$ T(\varphi ) = T(\tau') + T(\varphi_0)T_1(\varphi) = T(\varphi_0)T_1(\varphi) = T_{T(\varphi_0)}(\varphi) $$ Thus $ T = T_{T(\varphi_0)} $. But I can't replicate this on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any proof for $\mathbb{R}^n $ would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by $T'$ in dimension $\geqslant 2$?

Comment: I think that $T'$ is some kind of distributional gradient.

Comment: Everything should be almost the same, take $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ the integral will be over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1}\cdots\int_{-\infty}^{x_n} \varphi(t)\mathrm{d}t_1\cdots\mathrm{d}t_n$, $\varphi = \nabla \tau$.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo In multi dimensions we see the relation of weak derivatives as $ D^\alpha T(\varphi) = (-1)^{|\alpha|}T(D^\alpha \varphi)$. So just like gradient $ T' = (D^{e_1}T,...,D^{e_n}T) $. In other words I mean that $ T'= 0 $ implies equivalently $ T(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x_i}) = 0 $ for all $ \varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: @Yimin It doesn't work that way. You are taking $\varphi $ (in the place of $\psi$) as a scalar function. But $ \nabla \tau $ is a vector. This is exactly the problem in multi dimensions where to use the decomposition of each $\varphi $ shown above along with the fact that $ T(\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x_i})= 0$ for all $i$ we need to have a $\tau \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n) $ such that $\frac{\partial\tau}{\partial x_i} = \psi $ for all $i$.

Comment: Here's [a related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/220128/8157) by Paul Garrett.