# distributions whose derivative is zero?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I just learned about the notion of tempered distributions $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$.

But it is unclear that if such a distribution has a 0 derivative (of course in the distribution sense) then it equals a constant function.

Similarly, is it true that if a distribution solves Laplace equation, then it must equal to a harmonic polynomial?

Comment: Tempered distribution are distributions (who could have thought...=) ), hence if $T\in \mathcal S'$ and $T'=0$, then $T$ can be represented by a constant function. I don't remember a similar result for Laplacian, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, zero derivative implies constant distribution. One way to see this is by mollification: if $T'=0$, then for any smooth mollifier $\phi$ we have
$$(T*\phi)' = T'*\phi = 0 $$
Since $T*\phi$ is a smooth function, it's identically constant. Then the distributional limit is constant of $T*\phi_\epsilon$ as $\epsilon\to 0$ is constant too.  (Here $\phi_\epsilon(t) = \epsilon^{-1}\phi(\epsilon^{-1} t)$, and one has to check that $T*\phi_\epsilon$ is independent of $\epsilon$.)

Another approach, which takes advantage of one-dimensional situation, is shown in the question here: [Solving $ T' = 0 $ for distributions in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/327324/). (There is no answer, but the question solves the 1-dimensional case.)

As for Laplacian: yes, you are correct. This is called [Weyl's lemma (for the Laplace equation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_lemma_%28Laplace_equation%29) and one of the proofs proceeds by mollification, as above. Again, $T*\phi_\epsilon$ is independent of $\epsilon$ by virtue of the mean value property, provided we use a radially symmetric mollifier.

Comment: I definitely remember writing an answer to "if a distribution $T$ satisfies $T'=0$ then $T$ is constant" not a week ago...