# Find distribution solution of differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I want to find solution of the equation $T' +aT =0$ where $T \in D'(\mathbb{R})$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

**What I have done so far:**

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax}T) = a e^{ax}T + e^{ax} \frac{dT}{dx} = e^{ax} \left(aT +  \frac{dT}{dx} \right) = 0$$

This means that the distribution $e^{ax}T$ is induced by some constant $c$.

Comment: You want to show that the only solution $T\in D'(\mathbb R)$ is $T\varphi = \int e^{ax}\varphi(x)\,dx$?

Comment: @amsmath Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if the distributional derivative of a distribution $f$ is $0$ then $f(\psi) = c \int \psi(x) dx$ for some $c$ (see e.g. the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205438/distributions-whose-derivative-is-zero)).

As a result, we know that $T(e^{ax} \psi) = c \int \psi(x) dx$ for each compactly supported test function $\psi$. If $\psi$ is a compactly supported test function then so is $e^{-ax}\psi$. Therefore, we see that
$$T(\psi) = T(e^{ax} e^{-ax} \psi) = c \int e^{-ax} \psi(x) dx$$
so that $T$ is the regular distribution induced by $c e^{-ax}$ as desired (note that you can't hope to get rid of $c$ since the differential equation is linear and has no additional data).

Comment: I dont think that the following is a good notation: $T(e^{ax} \psi) = c \int \psi(x) dx$. Because the distribution that we are talking about here is not $T$ but $e^{ax}T$

Comment: The definition of $e^{ax} T$ is that $e^{ax} T(\psi) = T(e^{ax} \psi)$. This is not a new choice of notation - I am precisely applying the distribution $T$ to the test function $e^{ax}\psi$.