# What is the fundamental property of the Fourier operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, diagonalization

It is well-known that the Fourier transform satisfies the following translation property:
$$[\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{T}_hf)](\xi) = \text{e}^{2 \pi \text{i} \xi h} \cdot [\mathcal{F}(f)](\xi),$$
where $\mathcal{T}_h$ is the translation operator defined by $f(x) \mapsto f(x + h)$. By further defining the derivative operator as
$$\mathcal{D} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mathcal{T}_h - \mathcal{I}}{h},$$
one can show that
$$
[\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{Df})](\xi) = 2 \pi \text{i} \xi \cdot [\mathcal{F}(f)](\xi)
$$
by linearity and continuity arguments. I'm wondering if it's also possible to prove the convolution theorem, just using the translation property of the Fourier transform? I know that in the finite dimensional case, a (circluar) convolution can be represented by a circulant matrix, which can in turn be written as a polynomial in simple translation matrices.

More generally, my question is:

*Is the fundamental property of the Fourier operator that it diagonalizes translations?*

That is, if we define $(\mathcal M_h \varphi)(\xi) = \text{e}^{2 \pi \text{i} \xi h} \cdot \varphi(\xi)$, is the Fourier operator $\mathcal{F}$ fundamentally characterized by
$$
\mathcal{F} \circ \mathcal{T}_h = \mathcal M_h \circ \mathcal{F} \ ?
$$

Comment: "Is the fundamental property of the Fourier operator that it diagonalizes translations?" Yes. I asked [a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/220098/8157) several years ago. It looks a bit cringy now after all these years, but roughly I was trying to ask the same thing as you, only much more clumsily.

Comment: @giuseppe Ah yes, I saw your post actually. You were asking about diagonalization of the derivative, which is also briefly mentioned in my post. However it seems to me that translation is a more fundamental operation, and was wondering whether that gives the most general characterization of Fourier transforms.

Comment: This is why I said "roughly". Modulo that, my question is the same as yours. Notice that this is just cosmetics: diagonalizing translations or diagonalizing derivatives is exactly the same thing. Indeed, derivatives are the infinitesimal generators of translations. You observed that FT diagonalizes derivatives, because it diagonalizes translation. But the opposite is also true. Formally at least, $f(x-t)=(e^{t\frac{d}{dx}}f)(x)$, so if $\mathcal F$ diagonalizes $\frac{d}{dx}$ it will diagonalize $f(\cdot -t)$, too.

Comment: NOTE: I am sure there is a more direct way to answer your question "[...]prove the convolution theorem, just using the translation property of the Fourier transform?", that does not involve going through the linked question of mine. My previous comment is just a conceptual one.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clearing that up. My goal ultimately is to understand the Fourier transform as abstractly as possible. I guess you can define it for tempered distributions on locally compact groups, and I was thinking it would be very nice to characterize it completely by something like diagonalization of group translations, or something along those lines.

Comment: Assume $\mathcal F$ is continuous from $L^1$ into $L^\infty$ and from $L^2\to L^2$. We claim that, for $f,g\in L^1\cap L^2$ we have $\mathcal F(f*g)=\hat f\hat g$. To prove it, it suffices by density and linearity to assume that $f\in \mathcal C_0$ and $g=\chi_{[a,b]}$. In that case: ($\check f(x):=f(-x)$, $F$ is a $\mathcal C_0$ antiderivative of $f$)

$$\mathcal F(f*g)=\mathcal F\int_a^b \check f(y-x)dy=\mathcal F(-\check F(b-x)+\check F(a-x))=\mathcal F(F(x-a)-F(x-b))$$. Using the translation property and the result about derivatives, the result should follow.

Comment: Without some continuity assumption, I would expect the result to be false. After all, we have $2^{\aleph_0}$ equations, while there are $(2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ algebraic automorphisms of $L^2$.